# I made a function that put data into a data.frame, how do I pull this data.frame out of the function?

Tags: r, function, data.table, local

Here is a function I made. Its not complicated. Basically uses data you input to make vectors in a data table and add up one row. It spits out a list that is the sum of a row and also a data table!

```
q4PV<- function(cfs,ttms,i) {
  cash_flows<-cfs 
  cash_flows<-data.frame(cash_flows)
  cash_flows$ttm<-ttms
  cash_flows$rates<-i/100
  cash_flows$present_values<-cash_flows$cash_flows*(1/(1+cash_flows$rates)^cash_flows$ttm)
  results<-list(Data=cash_flows,Total_Present_Value=sum(cash_flows$present_values))
  return(results)
}


# Here I gave it some info and it worked great!
q4PV(cfs=c(1100, -500, 1900, 1800, 2000, 100, 1400, 1900, 400, 800),
     ttms=c(3,4,5,6,7,10,11,14,16,18),
     i=c(15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15))


# To my surprise, it spit this out, as I wanted:
$Data
   cash_flows ttm rates present_values
1        1100   3  0.15      723.26786
2        -500   4  0.15     -285.87662
3        1900   5  0.15      944.63580
4        1800   6  0.15      778.18967
5        2000   7  0.15      751.87408
6         100  10  0.15       24.71847
7        1400  11  0.15      300.92051
8        1900  14  0.15      268.52445
9         400  16  0.15       42.74591
10        800  18  0.15       64.64410

$Total_Present_Value
[1] 3613.644
```

Here is my problem, I am new to R and being able to use this table would be great. But its local to the function, is there anyway to get around this?! So I don't have to create another data.table when it already did it for me!

Thank you
Aaron S

Comment: `my_table <- q4PV(YOUR_PARAMETERS)`

Answer (score 1):

Here, it's unnecessary to create a function. To check the following code

```
library(data.table)
cfs = c(1100, -500, 1900, 1800, 2000, 100, 1400, 1900, 400, 800)
ttms = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 16, 18)
i = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)

DT <- data.table(cash_flows = cfs,
                 ttm = ttms,
                 rates = i/100)

# Create present_value column
DT[,present_value := cash_flows / (1 + rates)^ttm]

# DATA
DT[,.(cash_flows)]

# Total_present_Value
DT[,sum(present_value)]
```